# SpringBoot 3 & Spring Security 6 MockMvc 404 error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, mockmvc

In the api test through postman, the api works normally, but in the test through mockmvc, a 404 error appears.

My Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
@EnableWebMvc
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("/hi")
    public ResponseEntity<String> hi(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>("hi", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

My SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers()
                .addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(
                        XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter.XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN))
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .anyRequest().permitAll())
        ;
        return http.build();
    }
```

My Test Class

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SecurityConfig.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
class UserControllerTest {
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Get check")
    void getCheck() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/login/hi"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

What should I Do?

Even Spirng Security's docs doesn't come out right.

===============EDIT======================

My UserEntity

```
package com.hansung.capstone.user;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AppUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;

    private String password;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    }
```

My User createForm

```
package com.hansung.capstone.user;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
public class UserCreateForm {
    private String username;
    private String password1;
    private String password2;
    private String email;
}
```

My UserRepository

```
package com.hansung.capstone.user;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<AppUser, Long> {
    Optional<AppUser> findByusername(String username);
}
```

My UserService

```
package com.hansung.capstone.user;

import com.hansung.capstone.DataNotFoundException;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    public AppUser create(String username, String password, String email) {
        AppUser user = new AppUser();
        user.setUsername(username);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(password));
        this.userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }


    public Boolean check(AppUser req){
        Optional<AppUser> appuser = this.userRepository.findByusername(req.getUsername());
        if (!appuser.isPresent()){
            throw new DataNotFoundException("AppUser Not Found");
        }
        if (req.getUsername().equals(appuser.get().getUsername()) && passwordEncoder.matches(req.getPassword(), appuser.get().getPassword())){
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        } else{
            return Boolean.FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

My SecurityConfig

```
package com.hansung.capstone;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        authorize ->
                                authorize
                                        .requestMatchers("/login/ho").fullyAuthenticated()
                                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .formLogin(withDefaults());
        ;
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
# DATABASE
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/local
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=

# JPA
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

build.gradle()

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.hansung'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.2')
    testRuntimeOnly('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.2')
    compileOnly('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')

}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

ErrorContent

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@44065156 testClass = com.hansung.capstone.UserControllerTest, locations = [], classes = [com.hansung.capstone.CapstoneApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@6dee4f1b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@9da1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@bb57d28, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@ce77c022, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@13d73fa, [ImportsContextCustomizer@44ed0a8f key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jsonb.JsonbAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcSecurityConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebTestClientAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@189aa67a, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@112f364d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.test.context.web.socket.MockServerContainerContextCustomizer@1b765a2c, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@96666a5e], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@44065156 testClass = com.hansung.capstone.UserControllerTest, locations = [], classes = [com.hansung.capstone.CapstoneApplication], contextInitializerClasses = [], activeProfiles = [], propertySourceLocations = [], propertySourceProperties = ["org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTestContextBootstrapper=true"], contextCustomizers = [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.OverrideAutoConfigurationContextCustomizerFactory$DisableAutoConfigurationContextCustomizer@6dee4f1b, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.observability.ObservabilityContextCustomizerFactory$DisableObservabilityContextCustomizer@9da1, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.filter.TypeExcludeFiltersContextCustomizer@bb57d28, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@ce77c022, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@13d73fa, [ImportsContextCustomizer@44ed0a8f key = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jsonb.JsonbAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.task.TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcWebDriverAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcSecurityConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebTestClientAutoConfiguration]], org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@189aa67a, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@112f364d, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.test.context.web.socket.MockServerContainerContextCustomizer@1b765a2c, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestAnnotation@96666a5e], resourceBasePath = "src/main/webapp", contextLoader = org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader, parent = null]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:191)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:130)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:241)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:382)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:376)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:288)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController' defined in file [/Users/devch96/Desktop/workspace/cap/server/capstone/build/classes/java/main/com/hansung/capstone/UserController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.hansung.capstone.user.UserService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:245)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
    at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915)
    at app//org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at app//org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:59)
    at app//org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:47)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1386)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:543)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
    at app//org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:184)
    at app//org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:118)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.hansung.capstone.user.UserService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1812)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1371)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at app//org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    ... 111 more
```

Comment: This test doesn't even compile. But I would first remove all annotations but the `@WebMvcTest` and auto wire the `MockMvc` (assuming you aren't doing that already).

Comment: Please add yuour full test. Your controller uses a dependency which you need to mock. Add a field of type `UserService` to your test and add the `@MockBean` annotation on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a so called "Spring Boot Test Slice" (`@WebMvcTest`) which just configures everything related to the web layer. That is fine. This slice will find your controllers and also pick up your security config.

However, you added `@ContextConfiguration`. From the docs:

> {@code @ContextConfiguration} defines class-level metadata that is used to determine
> how to load and configure an {@link org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
> ApplicationContext} for integration tests.

With this, you are effectively disabling the automatic discovery of your `UserController` and you just get the security config. Nothing more. MockMVC will have probably shown you a 404 error.

How to fix this? Just remove it :)
But when you do so, your custom Spring Security config will go away during tests, too.

To fix this, you have two options: You can import additional config classes on the slice like this:

```
@WebMvcTest(includeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = SecurityConfig.class))`
```

OR do a full integration test like this:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
```

The latter will bring up everything (but an embedded server, but that can be done, too).

As you originally asked for the slice, here's my recommendation (Note that you don't need the extension nor the trickery with the config):

```java
package com.example.demo;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers.print;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan.Filter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

@WebMvcTest(includeFilters = @Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = SecurityConfig.class))
class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Get check")
    void getCheck() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/login/hi"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser("Michael")
    void testWithUser() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/login/ho"))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().string("hi Michael"));
    }
}
```

I added a 2nd method to the controller and changed the security config a bit to made clear how to test *with* a mock user:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(
                authorize ->
                    authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/login/ho").fullyAuthenticated()
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
            )
            .formLogin(withDefaults());
        ;
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

and the controller:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/hi")
    public ResponseEntity<String> hi() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("hi", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/ho")
    public ResponseEntity<String> ho(Authentication d) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("hi " + d.getName(), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Please note as well that you should really not put `@Configuration` on classes that are actually implementing your business. Separate those (I am referring to adding `@EnableWebMvc` to the controller… Also, the annotation itself is superfluous anyhow with the Spring Boot Web MVC starter).

Full `pom.xml` for reference, too:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: When I wrote your code as a demo, I confirmed that it works. But it doesn't work for my code. 
I will edit the entire code, gradle contents, and error contents and upload them.

Comment: This is the github address with the full code.
https://github.com/devch96/temp/tree/main/server/capstone